# Meaning of "It’s stuff like that" in a sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

In episode 8 of *Friends*, four of them are waiting for Chandler and Joey. They all are going to a funeral. One of Monica's relatives had died. Then, Chandler and Joey arrive and say:

> Joey: Morning. We ready to go?
>
> Chandler: Well, don’t we look nice all dressed up? **It’s stuff like that**, isn’t it?

So they went away. I couldn't understand what Chandler meant in the bold expression. Between his two questions, the others react as like that time was not a good moment to Chandler's comment. Therefore I guess in the second question he shows that the first one hadn't been pertinent. If someone could help me, I'd be grateful! Thanks a lot!

Comment: btw, it the phrase is "(A relative) of Monica" not "A (relative of Monica)", so when you change to "of Monica" it become "Monica's relative" (no "a"). To make the relative indeterminate, say "One of Monica's relatives".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I took a look at a script [here](http://friends.tktv.net/Episodes1/summaries/8.html) and apparently, at the beginning of the episode, one of the characters thought Chandler was gay. Chandler couldn't understand why people would think that. Throughout the episode, he tries to find out why people think that about him.

Later, while complimenting Joey, another man, he realized his compliment (and possibly the way he said it) could be construed as gay:

> Well, don’t we look nice all dressed up? It’s stuff like that [that makes you/others think I'm gay], isn’t it?

Edit: I just watched the episode. He was actually addressing the entire group. Still, after he complimented the group, he realized that those kinds of comments might be the reason why people got the impression that he was gay.

Comment: And to add context for any ELL learner unfamiliar with this unfortunate aspect of North American popular culture (at least when *Friends* was made): For a man for have almost any opinion on dress or fashion is construed as a sign of his being gay.

Answer (score 3):

Without a lot of context it doesn't make any sense.

My guess is people have told Chandler in the past that he lacks tact. So he meant:

"It's stuff like that [that makes me sound like an ass], isn't it?"